# What does (reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this)) mean?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and doing my first project. I cannot understand this line:

```
(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this))
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `someFunction(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this))`?  If so, it's an attempt to pass some object (hopefully of a trivial class) to a function as a sequence of bytes, along with its byte count.

Comment: Could we see a little more code? Maybe if there is more to that error too?

Comment: @PepijnKramer it is not undefined behavior. It is actually well-defined behavior to cast a pointer to an object to a `char*` to access the raw bytes of the object.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you'd use if you wanted to hexdump an object, or to copy an object to a binary file.  You'd get a `char *` and a `size_t` that describe a generic buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah me bad, it is the other way around. Casting a char* to an object is not correct. What I wanted to say is that the actual content of what the pointer points to differs depends on the compiler and its settings. (padding/alignment etc).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in the context of passing these two values as arguments to a function, certainly in the context of a class. Maybe you're just seeing this all around and wondering why it keeps coming up...

---

This is a relatively common pattern when serializing* an instance of a class. Let's break it down into the two parts (aka "arguments").

## `reinterpret_cast<char*>(this)`

- `reinterpret_cast<A>(B)` means whatever `B` is, actually treat it as `A`
- `char*` is a pointer to a `char`
- `char` is basically just a byte
- `this` is a "pointer" to the current class, of whatever type.
- A "pointer" to something literally is the location in memory of the first byte that represents that something

So we're getting a **pointer to the first byte**, in memory, that represents `this`'s class.

## `sizeof(*this)`

- `sizeof(A)` gets the number of bytes it takes to hold whatever type A is
- `*this` gets the value of the pointer
- `this` (again) is a "pointer" to the current class, of whatever type.

So we get the **number of bytes**, in memory, that are used to represent `this`'s class.

## Why?

### Serialization

There are lots of APIs in C/C++ that need to use a block of bytes, in particular when interfacing with things outside of pure software world, storing or transmitting blocks of data, which very often needs a way to "serialize" the data in question.

The location and the length/size (the arguments to the function) are the minimum bits of information needed to describe a block of memory, aka a block of bytes. You'll see this kind of thing when you're serializing a class.

### Example class that might use this

These days it's common to need to send "pixel" data out over a serial line to control "addressable" LEDs. It might be helpful to do something like this:

```
// Some function that sends the raw bytes on the wire to the WS2812 pixels
extern void sendBytes(char const * bytes, size_t num);

struct Pixel {
  // WS2812 uses GRB order instead of RGB :(
  uint8_t g;
  uint8_t r;
  uint8_t b;

  void display() {
    sendBytes(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this));
  }

  // Other functions
};
```

Comment: One should keep in mind that not every class can be serialized in this way.

Comment: @Evg Good point. I just wanted to cover some basics. I'd invite an edit that clarifies the things to watch out for.